# ldapsearch operations error: DSID-0C0906E8

Tags: authentication, spring-security, ldap

I am trying test ldap binding with our institutional ldap server using `ldapsearch` command.

Here is the configuration from a web application using Spring for ldap authentication.

```
<beans:bean id="contextSource"
            class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="ldap://ldap.xxx.edu:389/DC=xxx,DC=edu" />
    <beans:property name="userDn" value="ou=institution,ou=people" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="password" />
</beans:bean>
```

The command I ran is

```
ldapsearch -h ldap.xxx.edu -p 389 -x -b "dc=xxx,dc=edu"
```

I got the following error:

```
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=xxx,dc=edu> with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: ALL
#

# search result
search: 2
result: 1 Operations error
text: 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C0906E8, comment: In order to perform this ope
 ration a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v1db1

# numResponses: 1
```

The error message is kind of vague. It does not really say what exactly it is caused by. Anything wrong with my ldapsearch command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the bind credentials (userDN and password) like this:

```
ldapsearch -h ldap.xxx.edu -p 389 -D "ou=institution,ou=people,dc=xxx,dc=edu" -w password -x -b "dc=xxx,dc=edu"
```

Comment: Still getting `ldap_bind: Invalid credentials`, `DSID-0C0903A9`

Comment: I just updated my response. I think I missed the baseDN in the bindDN option (-D). Can you try again?

Comment: No error this time. However it prints out a bunch of stuff but I don't even see my cn (djiao) in the output.

Comment: If you want to search for a specific user you need to add a search filer. Just add the filter at the end of the command:
`ldapsearch -h ldap.xxx.edu -p 389 -D "ou=institution,ou=people,dc=xxx,dc=edu" -w password -x -b "dc=xxx,dc=edu" "(cn=djiao)"`